# How to use JavaScript variable in Haml?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have a javascript function (available on all pages as it's included in application.js) that detects if the browser has Flash support and outputs true or false.

Now, I want to show a flash based price chart if true and a HTML/Javascript based chart if false.

At the top of a Haml page I try to pass the result of the javascript function to HAML like this:

```
:javascript
  if (browserHasFlashSupport())
    #{showFlashChart = true}
```

And use it in Haml further down on the page like this:

```
- if showFlashChart
    # show flash chart
- else
    # show html/js chart
```

But I can't get it to work as the ruby variable showFlashChart is "true" no matter what - but in console, the javascript function browserHasFlashSupport() returns true/false like it should, so I must be doing something wrong.

I guess it would probably be the best solution just to use the javascript functions "return true/false" directly in HAML like `- if browserHasFlashSupport()` if that's possible and the "right" way to do it?

I'd appreciate any help, thanks :-)

PS. Any tips on how to avoid the usage of inline javascript in my HAML file would be very welcome too.

Comment: haml?? you mean `html`??

Comment: No, I mean Haml (if you don't know Haml, see http://haml.info/) :)

Comment: oops!! sorry first time i hear about it!

Comment: Have you consider using `gon`? https://github.com/gazay/gon

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminSinclaire but I need to do it the other way round - send a variable/function output from js to ruby (Haml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem of your solution:**

Your javascript function has to be run **in a client's browser** to detect if it has flash support.

Here is what happens when a user wants to get a page from your site:

1. User's browser sends request to your server.
2. Your server handles the request, **compiles views(e.g. HAML)**.
   *Also rails adds `<script>` tags to the output html page. These tags will contain urls to your scripts (defined in `application.js` or others).* Then the server responds with this html page.
3. User's browser loads compiled page from your sever.
4. The browser sees the `<script>` tags and automatically downloads javascript sources from specified urls.
5. And **only now** in the clients browser **your javascript functions may be run**.

You see that your haml template was rendered on the step 2 and your javascript function may be run only on step 5.

That is a lot simplified case. But it is impossible to make step 5 to precede step 2 (without use of ajax or cookies). That is why your way is impossible.

Hope this is quite descriptive.

Comment: That makes great sense. Thanks! I'll use a cookie, I think.